# Can't update Matplotlib using pip under Python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib has released 3.4.2 version but my version is stuck in 3.3.4.
I removed pip cache and tried, didn't work.

> $pip3 install -U matplotlib==3.4.2
> ERROR: Could not find a version that
> satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.4.2 (from versions: 0.86,
> 0.86.1, 0.86.2, 0.91.0, 0.91.1, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1rc1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0b4, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.1.0rc1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 3.0.0rc2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.1.0rc1, 3.1.0rc2, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.2.0rc1, 3.2.0rc3, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.3.0rc1, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib==3.4.2

python: 3.6.9
pip: 21.1.3

Comment: From https://matplotlib.org/stable/devel/min_dep_policy.html Matplotlib 3.4 needs Python 3.7+

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this, you can try `pip install matplotlib==3.4.2`. It should work fine

Comment: No, it's the same. Need python >= 3.7.

Comment: thanks . you are right. I didn't notice the android version